# VS2013 freezes when working with a javascript file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a site and I need to make some changes to a javascript file.  Any time I do something VS2013 freezes for about 30 seconds.  So just typing `$` takes 30 seconds.  If I use `go to definition` it takes about 2 minutes.

This is not my code, it is code from an envato template.  There are a lot of JsHint warnings on the code but it is functioning ok in the browser so there is no benefit for me to go through all the code files fixing the warnings, I just need to modify a few functions but at the rate of 30 secs per char its going to take a long time.

Just having the code file open (with tab selected) slows everything down including the right click context menu in the solution explorer.

My own javascript files are fine with no speed delay so its something in the code that is causing the IDE to slow down but going through it line by line and refactoring it is more than the job is worth.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?  I Know I can just use a different editor but I'd rather not have to and also want to get to the bottom of why its happening. I am guessing it must be some intellisense related issue.  How do I go about debugging that?  Can I turn intellisense off for an individual file?

Comment: I have the same problem when editing some javascript files of less than 200 lines of code. When the editor is 'calculating' an autocomplete option the editor hangs for a couple of seconds. This is really annoying! I hope someone has a fix for this problem? Could it be the Resharper plugin?

Comment: I ended up just editing with a text editor